# Lower bound $\langle (I + A)^{-1}x, x \rangle$ given that $\sigma_\text{max}(A) < 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a square real matrix such that the largest singular value $\sigma_\text{max}(A) = \sigma < 1$. I want to find a lower bound on $\langle (I + A)^{-1}x, x\rangle$ where $x$ is a vector of euclidean norm $1$: $\langle x, x\rangle=1$.

I empirically find that a seemingly tight lower bound is
$$
\langle (I + A)^{-1}x, x\rangle \geq \frac{1}{1+\sigma}
$$
which is reached for $A= \sigma I$. I cannot prove the above result.

Note that it is pretty straightforward to prove that $\sigma_\text{min}((I + A)^{-1}) \geq \frac1{1+\sigma}$ but that does not suffice to conclude, since I do not assume that $A$ is symmetric.

PS: $\sigma_\text{max}$ and $\sigma_\text{min}$ are the largest and smallest singular values: $\sigma_\text{max} = \sqrt{\lambda_\text{max}(AA^T)}$ is the operator norm of $A$.

Comment: Suggestions for better question: Explain notation $\sigma_{\text{max}}, \sigma_{\text{min}}$.  What norm used for vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $f(z)=(1+z)^{-1} - (1+\sigma)^{-1}$ maps the disk of radius $\sigma$ into the right half plane as a function of one complex variable.

Therefore, essentially by von Neumann's inequality, we get that $$\frac{f(A)+f(A)^*}{2}=\mathrm{Re }f(A)\geq 0$$ since $\|A\|\leq \sigma.$ Assuming $A$ has real entries, this implies the claim as
$$\langle (1+A)^{-1}x,x\rangle = \langle \mathrm{Re} (1+A)^{-1}x,x\rangle.$$

To see the calculation with von Neumann's inequality more explicitly, let $\psi(z) = \frac{z-1}{z+1}.$ Note $\psi$ takes the right half plane to the disk. So, $\psi \circ f$ takes the disk of radius $\sigma$ into the unit disk.
Therefore, von Neumann's inequality states that
$\|\psi \circ f(A)\|\leq \sup_{z\in \sigma\mathbb{D}} |\psi\circ f(z)| \leq 1.$
Note that $$1-(\psi \circ f(A))^*(\psi \circ f(A)) \geq 0.$$ (Here by $T\geq 0$ we mean that $T$ is positive semi-definite.)
Writing out what that means
$$1-(f(A)^*+1)^{-1}(f(A)-1)^*(f(A)-1)(f(A)+1)^{-1} \geq 0.$$
So,
$$(f(A)^*+1)(f(A)+1)-(f(A)^*-1)(f(A)-1)=2(f(A)+f(A)^*)\geq 0.$$

Results of the above form (positivity of noncommutative rational functions) always have to have "algebraic proofs," many of which can be done algorithmically. See, e. g.,
[Helton, Klep, and McCullough - The convex Positivstellensatz in a free algebra](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870812001892) and
[Pascoe - Positivstellensätze for noncommutative rational expressions](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2018-146-03/S0002-9939-2017-13773-3/home.html).

Comment: Thanks! I am unfamiliar with von Neumann's inequality: are you talinkg about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%27s_inequality ? If so, could you explain how it implies $f(A) + f(A)^T \geq 0$ ? (Sorry I forgot to mention that everything is real here).

Comment: @PAb I added an explanation at the bottom. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @PAb and yes that was the theorem I was talking about.

Comment: Small typo: $\psi$ rather maps the right half plane to the unit disk. Thanks for the neat trick !